# How to create tooltip using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

Once user select value from tree dropdown I want to call service for tool-tip associated with label to show description of the selected text in the input field. How can i achieve the task using AngularJS tool-tip feature and get the description. I am new to AngularJS any detail help will be appreciated.

So far tried Code..

Ctrl.js

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 fieldHeight">
    <label for="erh" class="col-md-5 required">Enterprise Reporting Hierarchy:
        <span ng-mouseover="tooltip={{erhHirachyInfo.erhToolTip}}" 
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign pull-right"></span>
    </label>
<div class="col-md-7">
    <div multiselect-dropdown-tree ng-model="nonPersistentProcess.erhKey"      
    options="erhTreeviewOptions">
    </div>
</div>
```

service.js

```
 return $resource('app/prcs/rest/process/getERhHirachyInfo/:id', {}, {
        'query': {
            method: 'GET'
        },
        'get': {
            method: 'GET'
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular team developped a directive for this purpose:

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips